# Java Program Not Drawing Vertical Grid

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, paintcomponent

So I have the following code (sorry if its messy), and when the I press the button "Show Vertical Grid" It doesn't want to switch the vertical grid on. Can anybody fix this please? Im all out of idea's.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private GridPane gridPane;

public static square s =  new square();

public boolean isMouseClicked = false;

public static JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();




public int gridY = 1;
public int gridX = 1;


public Game() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

   OptionPanel options = new OptionPanel();
   options.addActionListener(this);
   add(options, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    gridPane = new GridPane();
    add(gridPane);


}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Game game = new Game();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setTitle("Game");
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(game);


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("grid")) {
        gridPane.setGridOn(!gridPane.isGridOn());
    }

    if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("square")){
        gridPane.setSqaureOn(!gridPane.isSquareOn());
    }
}

public class GridPane extends JPanel {

    private boolean gridOn = false;
    private boolean squareOn = false;
    private boolean vertOn;

    public GridPane() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public boolean isGridOn() {
        return gridOn;
    }

    public boolean isSquareOn(){

        return squareOn;
    }

    public boolean isVertOn(){

        return vertOn;
    }

    public void setGridOn(boolean value) {
        if (value != gridOn) {
            this.gridOn = value;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void setVertOn(boolean value){

        if (value != vertOn){
            this.vertOn = value;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void setSqaureOn(boolean value){
        if (value != squareOn){
            this.squareOn = value;
            isMouseClicked = true;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

        if (gridOn) {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            for (int i = 0; i < tk.getScreenSize().height; i += 64){
                gridY++;
                g.drawLine(0, (64 * gridY), tk.getScreenSize().width,(64 * gridY));
            }
        }

        gridY = -1;

       gridX = -1;

       if(isSquareOn() && isMouseClicked == true){
           s.drawSquare(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x, MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y, 64, 64,g,new Color(255,255,255));
       }

       if (vertOn){
           g.setColor(Color.white);
           for (int ig = 0; ig < tk.getScreenSize().width; ig += 64){
              gridX++;
              g.drawLine((64 * gridX), 0,(64 * gridX),tk.getScreenSize().height);
          }
       }

 }


}

public class OptionPanel extends JPanel {

    public JButton grid;

    public JButton vgrid;

    public JButton square;

    public OptionPanel() {

        //Sets the stuff for the panel
        setBackground(new Color(155,0,255));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        //end

        //The Show Grid Button Stuff
        grid = new JButton("Show Horizontal Grid");
        grid.setActionCommand("grid");
        //end

        //The vertical grid
        vgrid = new JButton("Show Vertical Grid");
        vgrid.setActionCommand("vgrid");
        //end

        //The Square tool button stuff
        square = new JButton("Sqaure Tool");
        square.setActionCommand("square");
        //end

        //The gridbagConstraints things
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;


        //kind of like padding
        gbc.weighty = 1;

        //sets the positions
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        //add it
        add(grid, gbc);

        //changes position for the second button
        gbc.gridx = -1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        // adds it
        add(vgrid,gbc);

        //end


    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        //adds action listeners
        grid.addActionListener(listener);
        vgrid.addActionListener(listener);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reconcile this line:

```
vgrid.setActionCommand("vgrid");
```

with these lines:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("grid")) {
     gridPane.setGridOn(!gridPane.isGridOn());
  }

  if (e.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("square")) {
     gridPane.setSqaureOn(!gridPane.isSquareOn());
  }
}
```

Where does it check for the actionCommand given to the vertical grid button and then call the correct method to set the vertical grid state?

More importantly -- a useful debugging tool to learn and use is to sprinkle println statements through your code to see if methods that you think *should* be called are actually *being* called.

Comment: Oh thank you!! I didn't even realize that I hadn't added that piece of code yet! @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: @DennisMills: you're welcome. But again, the important nugget in this exercise is not my solution, but my process. You need to learn to debug. Put println's in methods to see if they're being called and to check the state of variables. Trace back in your code with more println's until you *isolate your error*. This is key!